# Combine ListView with Flow

Tags: model, qml, tableview, scrollview

I have wrapped a Flow inside a Scrollview as shown below.  I have it working well, and now want to replace the hard coded "GateWay" items with data from a model.  I want to keep the Flow, but how do I combined a ListView with a Flow?

In other words, "Gateway"  will become the delegate for a ListView model.

If I put a ListView in the Flow I assume it will be treated as one big item (vertically stacked).  I just want to flow the delegates of the ListView.  How can I do that?

```
ScrollView {
    clip: true
    contentHeight:  gatewayFlow.implicitHeight
    contentWidth:  parent.width // availableWidth // gatewayFlow.implicitWidth
    Flow {
        id: gatewayFlow
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10
        Gateway { }
        Gateway { }
        Gateway { }
        Gateway { }
        Gateway { }
        Gateway { }
        Gateway { }
        Gateway { }
        Gateway { }
    }  // Flow
} // ScrollView
```

Comment: You don't want a ListView. Replace the whole thing (including the ScrollView) with a GridView.

Comment: The GateWay component resizes itself to available space, so as the screen width increases the number of columns increase (in a Flow) and my delegate resizes.  Won't a GridView force me to a fixed number of columns?

Comment: No, GridView will automatically flow the cells to whatever number of columns fits width-wise and the number of rows necessary to fit them all (i.e. just like a Flow). You can even change it to flow column first instead (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#flow-prop).

Comment: I would also suggest using a Repeater inside the Flow instead of a ListView.

Comment: @fallerd I'd like to have sections in Flow like they are in ListView. What's the way to do it?